# Widget not showing up in Widget list

Tags: android, widget

I can't for the life of me figure out why my widget won't show up in my widget list. It's being installed on my device, and I can uninstall it just fine too, but it won't show up.
I have searched for hours, both yesterday and today, but I have been unable to find a solution. Even re-starting the widget from scratch and following the handbook's directions didn't help.

Here's all the XML files:

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.opdracht_208d4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".Photo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@layout/widget"/>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main"/>
```

I also have a dummy Activity class:

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

}
```

So, to keep this a legit question: Can someone please analyze what's wrong? I'll try to go through the code again to see what's wrong, hoping I can answer my own question, just in case.

Comment: Are you trying to make a Widget or a Live Wallpaper?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Been quite a hectic time for me;
I managed to fix the problem myself. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what I did wrong, but when changing this:

```
<action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
```

into this:

```
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
```

He widget showed up.